# SwiftUI UI Test How To Display Dynamic Buttons Text Values in an app.scrollViews?

Tags: xcode-ui-testing

How To Display Dynamic Buttons Text Values in an app.scrollViews?

I would like to able to tap the button inside first row in the scrollViews, but not sure what the index of the button is. I tried the 1, 2 and 3 with no luck.

```
let scrollViewsQuery = app/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.scrollViews/*[[".otherElements[\"Tabbar\"].scrollViews",".scrollViews"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
    let elementsQuery = scrollViewsQuery.otherElements
    elementsQuery.buttons.element(boundBy: 0).tap() //
    print("----------------------------------------------")
    var i = 0
    for element in elementsQuery.buttons.allElementsBoundByIndex{
        i += 1
        print(i)
        print(element) //How To Display the Button Text here?
       // print( elementsQuery.buttons.element(boundBy: i))
    }
```

Comment: Where did you come up with that scrollview query? It’s very complex and kind of scary. I’m not surprised it doesn’t function as you’d expect it. Can you simplify your definition of the scrollview you’re looking to use? Your call to the first button in it is correct, but I suspect you’re getting an odd result from your scrollview query.

Comment: Ah, looks like you used the test recorder to come up with that (I was just doing some work, rarely use the recorder, did for some odd thing and accidentally merged my code before replacing the "options" drop-down with a static value). Anyway, how many scrollViews are on your page when you are doing this? In your question you're asking how to display button text varies, but in your "what I want to do" you say you want to tap the first button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only have one scrollView present, the code to tap the first button in it would be the following:

```
let myScrollView = app.scrollViews.firstMatch
let myScrollViewsButtons = myScrollView.buttons
let myScrollViewsFirstButton = myScrollViewButtons.firstMatch

myScrollViewsFirstButton.tap()
```

A `button` in this context is an `XCUIElement`, not something that is particularly printable. Buttons do have `label` attributes that are generally the text displayed on them...